# ip camera streaming in asp.net web forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

i used this code in windows form application for streaming but now i'm using in asp.net web form. there is some error around picturebox1=bmp because web form have no picture box control

```
void stream_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs) { 
    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
}

private void btnstart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string httpip = "http:192.10.1.1:4747/mjpegfeed?960x720";
    stream = new MJPEGStream(httpip);
    stream.NewFrame += stream_NewFrame;
    stream.Start();
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: web form have image control and i have no idea how to bind "Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();" bmp to image control

Comment: A simple HTML image tag won't work because it only displays static images and doesn't refresh. https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=active&ei=3ThTWsWvHYXcwALPyrmQCg&q=html+stream+webcam+asp.net&oq=html+stream+webcam+asp.net&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1998.1998.0.2221.1.1.0.0.0.0.64.64.1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.v75a6UBgsv8 this is more complicated than just picking a new control, unless you can find a ready-made implementation.